# How to make ssh output tidy using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some output from ssh. I want to make it tidy using python

```
ip_address = "xxxx"
username = "xxx"
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address,username=username)
remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell() 
remote_connection.send("show run | i _20.20.20.20\n")               
time.sleep(5)
readoutput = remote_connection.recv(65000)
ssh_client.close()

print(readoutput)
```

Right now I get:

```
RouterA#show run | i _20.20.20.20
 neighbor 20.20.20.20 remote-as 202025
 neighbor 20.20.20.20 password password
  neighbor 20.20.20.20 activate
crs1.ams1#
```

Also in Html I get this!!

```
b'\r\nRouterA#show run | i _10.10.10.10\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 remote-as 1010\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 password password1010\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 activate
```

What I want is This:(without \n in output)

```
""""
RouterA#show run | i _20.20.20.20
neighbor 20.20.20.20 remote-as 202025
neighbor 20.20.20.20 password password
neighbor 20.20.20.20 activate
RouterA#

"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
for line in readoutput.split('\n'):
    print(line.strip())
```

in case of the html output, which is a bytestring:

```
html = b'\r\nRouterA#show run | i _10.10.10.10\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 remote-as 1010\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 password password1010\r\n neighbor 10.10.10.10 activate'
for line in html.decode().split('\r\n'):
    print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
RouterA#show run | i _10.10.10.10
neighbor 10.10.10.10 remote-as 1010
neighbor 10.10.10.10 password password1010
neighbor 10.10.10.10 activate
```

Comment: @sansan try the new version, please. If it is still not working, can you please tell me what is the output of `type(readoutput)`

Comment: This is the type <type 'str'>

Comment: I still get the /n in my Html

Comment: I have tried this: bus still not working the spaces are ok now. a = """{}""".format(readoutput)

Comment: Because your html is a bytestring, plus it has both \r and \n. Try html.decode().split('\r\n')